# Find alphanumeric characters, text and replace with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm trying to find and replace text in an HTML. And adding a bold element around the text.

For example, lets say I have the following text:

```
<div>This is a test content and I'm trying to write testimonial of an user.</div>
```

If user searches for "test" in my HTML string, I need to show all text containing search text in bold.

```
<div>This is a <b>test</b> content and I'm trying to write <b>test</b>imonial of an user.</div>
```

This is working using the below code:

```
$.fn.wrapInTag = function(opts) {

var o = $.extend({
    words: [],
    tag: '<strong>'
}, opts);

return this.each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html();
    for (var i = 0, len = o.words.length; i < len; i++) {
        var re = new RegExp(o.words[i], "gi");
        html = html.replace(re, o.tag + '$&' + o.tag.replace('<', '</'));
    }
    $(this).html(html);
});
$('div').wrapInTag({
   tag: 'b',
   words: ['test']
});
```

But the above javascript approach fails if I search something like:
*test or /test
Regex doesn't support here.
There are multiple approaches over net but none of them worked for alphanumeric text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would perform the text highlight:

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    $("#text").html($("#text").html().replace("<b>", "").replace("</b>", ""));
    var reg = new RegExp($(this).val().replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1"),"g"); 
    $("#text").html($("#text").text().replace(reg, "<b>"+$("#search").val()+"</b>"));
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/frzv0dnL/2/)

Comment: still does not work for search strings like "*test" https://jsfiddle.net/frzv0dnL/1/

Comment: @RadekPech Updated the code accord to urs, it works now :)

Comment: @Ahs N :This is what I want. But It doesn't work for "*Test*" . Ideally it should also take the Caps char.

Comment: @ManuSingh: to ignore capitals just add "i" into the second param of the RegExp()

Comment: @RadekPech If I'll add "i", it will ignore the capitals but will also change my original text. If i'll search "Test" in below sentence:
This is a *test* content and I'm trying to write testimonial of an user.
my text will become 
This is a *Test* content and I'm trying to write testimonial of an user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the RegExp input. See [How to escape regular expression in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript)

```
function escapeRegExp(string){
    return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
```